# Link 2 repositories to 2 domain names on github pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a domain name www.abc.com
I have been successfully able to link it to my gh-pages of that repo by:

1. having only one CNAME entry in the gh-pages branch
2. Adding the A record at my DNS provider for Github IP.

Following the [**Github tutorial**](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages).

However, I now plan to have **2 different repos for 2 websites** in the same github user name.

I have 2 domain names now.
They are normally accessible using github-pages as follows:

- https://user-name.github.io/**repo-one**/
- https://user-name.github.io/**repo-two**/

I want to be able to point

- **`www.abc.com`** to `user-name.github.io/repo-one/`, and
- **`www.def.com`** to `user-name.github.io/repo-two/`

Kindly guide. Help appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. How is the second time any different from the first?

Comment: The same steps do not work

Comment: you're going to have to give us a much better problem description than "the same steps do not work".

Answer (score 0):

Add a CNAME with abc.com into the first repo, and def.com into the second repo. Remember to put your website code into the gh-pages branch. It worked for me.

However, I the second repo is not appearing in searches, as if the page is not indexed. Anyone have a solution?